# Array Split in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to get column string_1 and string_2 from column strings which is nested. Mix of array & split isn't working. Any help is appreciated, TIA! When I tried this but doesn't work:

```
ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT(SPLIT(r, '/abc')[safe_ordinal(1)]), FROM UNNEST(table) r)  as string_1,
ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT(SPLIT(r, '/abc')[safe_ordinal(2)]), FROM UNNEST(table) r)  as string_2,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track - this can be solved without groupings/joins. I think the most performant (parallelizable) solution with the least computation steps is a subquery on the array that creates new arrays of structs that contain the solutions of the given sub-rows:

```sql
with test_data as (
  select * from unnest([
    struct(1 as num, ['/a/abc/1','/a/abc/2','/a/abc/3'] as strings),
    (2,['/b/abc/1','/b/abc/2','/b/abc/3']),
    (3,['/c/abc/1','/c/abc/2','/c/abc/3'])
  ])
)

-- select * from test_data
select 
  num,
  array( -- create new array of structs with solution
    select as struct
      s as str,
      split(s,'/abc/')[0] as string_1,
      split(s,'/abc/')[1] as string_2
    from unnest(strings) as s
  ) as strings
from 
  test_data
```

resulting in
[image: query result]

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select num, any_value(strings) as strings, 
  array_agg(part[0]) as string_1, 
  array_agg(part[1]) as string_2
from your_data,
unnest(strings) string,
unnest([struct(split(string, '/abc/') as part)]) 
group by num
```

if apply to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]